# How to handle date conversion error in SQL?

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, error-handling, type-conversion

So I'm trying to convert strings in an SQL databse into datetime values.

I have some dates in a table like this:

```
23/12/2013 16:34:32
24/12/2013 07:53:44
24/12/2013 09:59:57
24/12/2013 12:57:14
24/12/2013 12:48:49
24/12/2013 13:04:17
24/12/2013 13:15:47
24/12/2013 13:21:02
24/12/2013 14:01:28
24/12/2013 14:02:22
24/12/2013 14:02:51
```

They are stored as strings unfortunately

And I want to convert them to datetime

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, analysed, 103 )
FROM OIL_SAMPLE_UPLOAD
```

However I get this message when I run the query

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Presumably because some values are badly formed (although I am yet to spot any of these)

It's ok if some values don't convert, I just need a way of handling this situation.

Something like  ISNULL(CONVERT(datetime, analysed, 103 )) would be good except that the convert function does not return NULL when it fails.

Comment: to be clear the strings are in dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss format

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use [**ISDATE()**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function to check whether value is valid date

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(analysed)=1 THEN CONVERT(datetime, analysed, 103 ) 
            ELSE '' END
FROM OIL_SAMPLE_UPLOAD
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to make any changes to the database I'm using. ie: I'd prefer to to change SET DATEFORMAT dmy; unless the change only exists for the duration of the query.

Comment: This doesnot do any changes to database , it is only for checking duration query execution

Comment: For this to work, I would need to SET DATEFORMAT to dmy.

Comment: I can fix this by using STUFF(STUFF(analysed, 4, 2, SUBSTRING(analysed, 1, 2)), 1, 2, SUBSTRING(analysed, 4, 2))

Answer (score 13):

You can use [TRY_CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) or [TRY_CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) functions

Comment: Note that these functions are only available in SQL Server 2012 onwards (110)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the date part then take a `SUBSTRING` and calculate the date as follows. This might get you the correct date part at least.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(analysed, 0, 11), 103 )
FROM OIL_SAMPLE_UPLOAD
```

Comment: needs to be 11 characters  
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(analysed, 0, 11), 103 )